# Why my min and max validation is not firing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular7

I have the template like below:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="configWeightage">
  <div class="example-container">
    Enter value in between 0 to 100    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        type="number"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        class="example-right-align"
        [formControlName]="weightageValue"
        id="weightage"
        required
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf="weightageValue.hasError('min(0)')" style="color: red"
      >Please enter greater than 0</mat-error
    >
    <mat-error *ngIf="weightageValue.hasError('max(100)')" style="color: red"
      >Please enter less than 100</mat-error
    >
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the class file

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder,FormGroup, Validators,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    
    /** @title Form field with prefix & suffix */
    @Component({
      selector: 'form-field-prefix-suffix-example',
      templateUrl: 'form-field-prefix-suffix-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['form-field-prefix-suffix-example.css'],
    })
    export class FormFieldPrefixSuffixExample {
      configWeightage:FormGroup;
      formBuilder : FormBuilder;
      weightageValueControl = new FormControl(['',Validators.required,Validators.min(0),Validators.max(100)]);
      hide = true;  
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
      ngOnInit() {
        
       this.configWeightage = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          'weightageValue' :this.weightageValueControl      
        }
    
       )
      }
    }
```

I am supposed the fire the error when there is a value NOT in between 0 and 100

But no validation message will be fired

Here is the stack bliz code for the same, so that you can run and fix yourself.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-dq8ntd?file=app/form-field-prefix-suffix-example.html

Comment: Fix the errors in your stackblitz. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors and typos you should fix in your Stackblitz :

- Remove brackets from `[formControlName]`
- Remove `min` and `max` attributes from `<input>` as you've already specified them using `validators`
- Move `<mat-error>` inside `<mat-form-field>`
- For the error condition, you should use `formGroupName.get('FormControlName').hasError('validatorName')`
- Remove `style="color: red"` from `<mat-error>`, this is already the default style for the error message.
- Fix the typo `this.formBuilder.group` to be `this.fb.group`

  Here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-klgonf?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html) after fixing the above errors.

Comment: Can you have a look here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642873/min-and-max-validation-is-firing-when-i-am-not-using-array-but-not-firing-when  this is similar issue , i change the controls to array controls still the validation is not firing